# Porcentaje de números mayores, iguales y menores a 0 de un array

Tags: javascript, array, algoritmos

Estoy intentando generar una una función que esté parametrizada y devuelva un array con resultados en porcentaje siguiendo un orden. El resultado final debe ser un array que muestre el porcentaje de valores mayores a cero, iguales a cero y menores que cero.

Ejemplo:

```
masMenos(1,2,0,-1)
```

debe dar por resultado:

```
0.5, 0.25, 0.25
```

Donde 0.5 es el porcentaje de números mayores a 0, 0.25 iguales a cero y 0.25 menores que cero.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

```js
    var array=[1,2,0,-1];
    function masMenos(array){
      var cantidad=1;
      for(var i =0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(array[i]>0){
          cantidad=(array[i]*cantidad)/100;
        }else if(array[i]==0){
          cantidad=(array[i]*cantidad)/100;
        }else {
          cantidad=(array[i]*cantidad)/100;
        }
      }return cantidad;
    }
    console.log(masMenos(1,2,0,-1));
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema con el código que incluiste en la pregunta?

Comment: Que solo me muestra un resultado, necesito que me muestre tres.

Comment: Pues tu variable `cantidad` es un humilde entero, así que ese es el primer cambio.

Comment: jajaja tienes razón jajaja @Alfabravo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de forma simple con la función `filter()`:

```js
    function masMenos(array){
      may=array.filter(num => num>0);
      igu=array.filter(num => num==0);
      men=array.filter(num => num<0);
      return {
        mayores: may.length/array.length,
        iguales: igu.length/array.length,
        menores: men.length/array.length
      };
    }
    
    console.log(masMenos([1,2,-1,0,1,0,1,0]));
```

La función `filter()` filtra los valores del array según una función dada (en este caso si son positivos, negativos o ceros).

Este método si bien es simple y legible no es el mas optimo, ya que cada vez que se emplea dicha función se recorre el array una vez.

Una opción más optima y recomendable que emplee un solo bucle es la siguiente:

```js
function masMenos(array, res=[0,0,0], n=array.length) {
    for (i in array)
      array[i]>0 ? res[0]++ : array[i]<0 ? res[2]++ : res[1]++
    return res.map(a =>a/n);
  }

  console.log(masMenos([1,2,-1,0,1,0,1,0]));
```

Desde luego las respuestas mas optimas pierden legibilidad.

Espero que la solución haya quedado mas clara, saludos.

Comment: Disculpa que no haya agregado mucho contenido, si gustas puedo agregar mas información.

Comment: Te agradezco la respuesta, me ha servido bastante

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo de nada, que tengas buen día.

Comment: Tú igual, de verdad gracias

Comment: Bien optimizado el codigo, Excelente!!

Comment: En realidad no es muy óptimo, porque se recorren tres veces el mismo array.

Comment: igual creo que lo mejor seria un reduce

Comment: @Emeeus estoy consciente de que el array se recorre 3 veces, pero la pregunta no indica buscar el método mas optimo, solo busca resolver el problema y solo brinde una forma simple y entendible de resolverlo.

Answer (score 3):

Si quieres que te muestre tres resultados, necesitas declarar y retornar un array, no una variable simple.  Puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
var array=[1,2,0,-1];
    function masMenos(array){      
      var cantidad = [0,0,0]
      for(var i =0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(array[i]>0){
          cantidad[0]+=1;
        }else if(array[i]==0){
          cantidad[1]+=1;
        }else {
          cantidad[2]+=1;
        }
      }
      cantidad[0] = cantidad[0]/array.length;
      cantidad[1] = cantidad[1]/array.length;
      cantidad[2] = cantidad[2]/array.length;
      return cantidad;
    }
    console.log(masMenos(array));
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Bien por usar solo una iteración, y no tres como la respuesta aceptada.

Answer (score 3):

Lo mas óptimo sería resolverlo en una sola iteración, y puede ser usando `for`, como ya han respondido, o `forEach`:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 0, -1];

let p = [0, 0, 0];
const inv = 1 / arr.length;

arr.forEach(e => e > 0 ? p[0] += inv : e < 0 ? p[2] += inv : p[1] += inv);

console.log(p);
```

se puede evitar dividir la cantidad por el total si uno hace la suma de las partes `1/largo`, porque aplicamos la propiedad distributiva (1+2)/2 = (1/2)+(2/2) .

Usando `reduce()` es casi lo mismo:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 0, -1];
const inv = 1 / arr.length;

const res = arr.reduce((p, c) => {
  c > 0 ? p[0] += inv : c < 0 ? p[2] += inv : p[1] = inv;
  return p;
}, [0, 0, 0]);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: +1 por espíritu deportivo